# In Tsung, how can I get publish message time in milisec?

Tags: erlang, tsung, erlang-escript

In Tsung, I want publish message time in milisec, I tried below but able to get time in Sec only.

```
<setdynvars sourcetype="eval" code='fun({Pid,DynVars})->
{{Year,Month,Day},{Hour,Minute,Second}} = erlang:localtime(),
io_lib:format(&apos;~4..0B-~2..0B-~2..0B::~2..0B:~2..0B:~4..0B\n&apos;, [Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second]) end.'>
<var name="time" />
</setdynvars> 

<request subst="true">

                <mqtt type="publish" topic="xxx" qos="0" retained="true">%%_time%%</mqtt>

            </request>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
1> Time_milli = fun() -> 
       Um = erlang:system_time(milli_seconds),
       {D,T} = calendar:gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(Um div 1000 + 719528*86400)
       {D,T,Um rem 1000}
   end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.54118792>
2> Time_milli().                                                                
{{2015,12,9},{8,13,53},40}
```

The value `719528*86400` is the number of seconds between the 1 1 1 at 0 0 0 and the 1970 1 1 at 0 0 0.

Note: the system_time is not monotonic, if you need this feature you can use erlang:monotonic_time/1, but in this case you cannot convert to a date or compare between different nodes.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I also tried with erlang:system_time(milli_seconds) but for this we need to build latest erlang/otp.